# Why does GNU configure define macros for SIZEOF_INT etc. as specific integer values?

Tags: c

If you're going to define these at all, why not define them as

```
#define SIZEOF_INT sizeof(int)
```

etc. so they are correct even if someone tries to use them to compile against a different architecture?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer a minute after asking the question. These macros are sometimes used in the predicates of #if etc. where sizeof calls cannot be evaluated.

For example

```
#if SIZEOF_LONG_LONG_INT == 8
stuff
#endif
```